# Find if attribute is inside the script tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Im using the following code to update inside specific script tag **attribute value** this is working but if I put an attribute name which is not inside the script it will create new one attribute with this name, how to avoid that that just if the attribute exist update it otherwise **do nothing**

This is the code

```
Content.find("#" + 'test-ui-boot').attr("src1", "test");
```

**this is the script for example**

```
<script id="test-ui-boot" src="/tcore.js"  data-aaa-ui-theme="bbb_val" src1="test" </script>
```

I use JQuery parser, how can I check if the attribute exist before doing this code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`attr()` returns undefined when the attribute does not exist

```
if(typeof Content.find("#" + 'test-ui-boot').attr("src1") !== 'undefined')
{
   Content.find("#" + 'test-ui-boot').attr("src1", "test");
}
```

Comment: Thanks I try it but I put the wrong attr name like src1 and still its find it and go inside the if statement...any idea?

Comment: Updated my post. You have to add `typeof` in the `if` check

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about jQuery, but in plain JavaScript, the function `.getAttribute()` returns `null` if the attribute does not exist. E.g. you can run the following against this very page :

```
z = document.getElementsByClassName('question-hyperlink")[0]
>>> <a class="question-hyperlink" href="/questions/36687960/find-if-attribute-is-inside-the-script-tag">

z.getAttribute('href')
>>>> "/questions/36687960/find-if-attribute-is-inside-the-script-tag"

z.getAttribute('theAttributeThatDontExist')
>>>> null
```